# Permission Issue: Creating postgres back as postgres user

Tags: shell, postgresql

I have following postgres backup script, its a shell script and written to run ans `postgres` user.

But the problem is `postgres` user doesn't have permission to write these directories. I as a user don't have `sudo` on these machines but I have changed the directory to has 755 and added to one of the group that has major permission to do read-write-execute. Since `postgres` user isn't part of the `unix` user group I guess I am running into this issue.

My goal is to put this in the cron-tab but prior to that I need to get the script running with proper permission:

```
#!/bin/bash
# location to store backups 
backup_dir="/location/to/dir"
# name of the backup file has the date
backup_date=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
# only keep the backup for 30 days (maintain low storage)
number_of_days=30
databases=`psql -l -t | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d'`
for i in $databases; do
  if [ "$i" != "template0" ] && [ "$i" != "template1" ]; then
    echo Dumping $i to $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date
    pg_dump -Fc $i > $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date
  fi
done
find $backup_dir -type f -prune -mtime +$number_of_days -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before doing this be sure to login as a super user (`sudo su`) and try executing these:

1. `useradd -G unix postgres` (Add postgres user to unix group)
2. `su postgres` (Login as postgres user)
3. `mkdir folder` (Go to the directory where postgres needs to write files)

***From this line down is my answer to @find-missing-semicolon question

Just to illustrate an example with a shell script, you can capture the password using the read command and put it to a variable. Here I stored the password in **password** and echoed it afterwards. I hope this helps.

```
`#!/bin/bash`

`read -s -p "Password: " password`
`echo $password`
```

Comment: Paul Pano I figured out a way to do it without actually using postgres user, i can run pg_dump as the database admin but the problem with that `pg_dump -Fc -Uga_db_admin mydatabase --password > $backup_dir\_$backup_date` shell script will prompt for a password is there away to avoid that.